# Does SCSS imported within React component only get compiled and used when component renders? (Performance)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, sass

First, I'm aware of CSS-in-JS solutions like `styled-components`, or using modules, but I'm curious about this specific implementation where the .scss is imported directly into the component. How does this actually work, and is there a performance improvement?

```
import './scss/parent.scss';
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent';

export default function ParentComponent() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    return (
        <div>
             {
                 items.map((item, i) => <ChildComponent key={i} />)
             }
        </div>
    )
}
```

My only thought right now is, that by importing these .scss files into the pages or components that they apply to, they reduce the overall size of the main CSS file, but will slightly increase render time of the specific page or component. Is this correct? Is this generally considered better for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. I'm running a NextJS app and I ran the production build

```
npm run build
```

Which compiles my `parent.scss` and the `global.scss` into a single CSS file. So:

- importing a component scss file into the Component itself does not improve performance, because the `.scss` is just compiled with the other `.scss` files into a single CSS file.
- I suppose the above could depend on how the bundler is configured.